# Events and handlers JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code in which  I want to display a word and sentence to my webpage when clicked(button). So far I have one text being displayed onto the page.I want to display the sentence after the text.The sentence is not displaying... anyone know why?

```
function handleButtonClick(){

    var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = handleButtonClick;


    var textInput = document.getElementById("word");
    var termName = textInput.value;

    var dt = document.createElement("dt");
    dt.innerHTML = termName;

    var dl = document.getElementById("p");

    dl.appendChild(dt);


    var textInput = document.getElementById("sentence");
    var termDefine = textInput.value;

    var dd = document.createElement("dd");
    dd.innerHTML = termDefine;

    var dl = document.getElementById("define");

    dl.appendChild(d);


}
window.onload = handleButtonClick;
```

Comment: What about dd why is that not appearing on the page?(or the input from the second textbox)

Comment: See my answer, you have a typo in your code: instead of dl.appendChild(d); you should have dl.appendChild(dd);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @sushanth already mentioned there is a typo in your code:

Instead of

```
 dl.appendChild(d);
```

It should be

```
 dl.appendChild(dd);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
```

supposed to be

```
button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
```

The second point is that the click event handler should be bound outside the function scope. Otherwise a new event will be bound every single time the function `handleButtonClick` fires.

```
var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);

function handleButtonClick() {
   // Your other code here
   // that excludes the click handler
}
```

And developer tools is your friend. Always use it to check for any errors.